# Django migrations ignoring db_table when set using metaclass

Tags: python, django, migration, metaclass, dbtable

I'm using a metaclass to automatically set my Django model db table names from camel case to '_' seperated names, e.g. `MyGreatModel` will have a table name like `appname_my_great_model` instead of the default `appname_mygreatmodel`:

```
class PrettyModelBase(ModelBase):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        super_new = ModelBase.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        module_name = camel_to_underscore(name)
        model_module = sys.modules[cls.__module__]

        app_label = super_new.__module__.split('.')[-2]
        db_table = '%s_%s' % (app_label, module_name)
        if not getattr(super_new._meta, 'proxy', False):
             super_new._meta.db_table = db_table

        return super_new


class BaseModel(models.Model):

    __metaclass__ = PrettyModelBase

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyGreatModel(BaseModel):
    somefield = models.TextField(default="")
```

However migrations doesn't seem to pick up this `db_table` name. If I run makemigrations, then `CreateModel` does not show `db_table` in the `options` for this model. If I hard-code it in the `class Meta` of `MyGreatModel` then it does. Moreover if I check the SQL to be run with `python manage.py sqlmigrate...` then it shows that it will create the `appname_mygreatmodel` table, not the delimited table name.

However if I do run this migration and then examine the model in the Django shell, then `MyGreatModel._meta.db_table` shows `my_great_model` as I would expect from my metaclass. If I manually add the `db_table` attribute the 0001 init migration options for CreateModel, then all is OK for subsequent migrations too, but Django should be doing that automatically I think...

Why is Django migrations not picking up the `db_table` here?

I'm using `Django==1.10.5`.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I'm not sure why that isn't working, but my advice would be to use the public `Meta` API rather than mucking around with `_meta`. Specifically, set `Meta.db_table` (from `attrs`) before calling `ModelBase.__new__()`. That will make you far less dependent on the internal details of Django's metaclass and migrations implementations.

Comment: Any luck yet? I am running into precisely the same issue. I'm trying to leverage Postgres schemas by setting all my table names to "app_label.model_name" instead of "app_label_model_name".

Comment: I just think this is a bad idea. Why do you want to change the names of your tables? Also, Django 1.10.5 is insecure. You need to update to at least 1.11, preferably 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

This question was re-raised on the django-developers mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/ncMCwMF2J3g/V3guuDbJCwAJ

Django migrations uses `model._meta.original_attrs` to determine the definition of the meta class: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/db/migrations/state.py#L454

Thus if you're dynamically mutating `model._meta` post-creation, you'll also need to mutate its `original_attrs` dict correspondingly. I think that should work (untested).